# sql command or Dynamic programming?

Tags: mysql, sql, dynamic-programming

suppose I have 1 GB of data in my database. I want to do something like this:

> If user searches for a sentence, say 'Hello world I am here.', the program should be able to return the data (rows) where this exact string is found and also the rows which have similar texts e.g., 'Hello world is a famous string, I am sure!'.

My question is: Which one will be more efficient- an sql command or a dynamic programming concept?

If sql is more efficient, what is the command that can be used for doing the same?

I am using mysql 5.6

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it

Comment: @bluefeet +1 - better questions get better answers.

Comment: your challenge will be to define 'similarity' and what exactly you think is close enough to match... for instance, would this match: 'Hllo waRld, I'm Hear!' be a match?

Comment: @Randy: no! for a normal user this will be a wrong result. By similarity I mean not the exact string (in terms of the distance b/w these words, not in terms of the spelling!) 'Hello world is a famous string, I am sure!' is more better than 'Hllo waRld, Im Hear!'
(at least for me).

Comment: ok (and i am not disagreeing) but these kind of 'rules' are what need to be defined programatically

Comment: also - look into WORDNET and SPARQL for semantic equivalences. - you might get things like 'hi everyone' is equivalent to 'hello world' -pretty fun to play with actually.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the full text capabilities of MySQL, which are documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html).

Basically, the data structure that you need is an inverted index.  For each word, this contains the positions of the word in all the documents.  With this information, you can start to piece things together.

In most cases, you are much better off doing this using established software, rather than writing your own.  I don't want to stop you, if you really want to, but the problem may be harder than you think.

Comment: definitely a difficult problem.

Comment: hey thanks for the answer.. Using dynamic programming I have almost done this part. But my mentor is asking 'why can't you use mysql?' That's why I want your help